# Does the IncludeAttribute add any value over the ObjectQuery and DbSet Include methods?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I am using WCF RIA Services in combination with the Entity Framework 4.0.

To ensure that related objects make it safely to the client, I need to first include them using the [ObjectQuery(Of T).Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) or [DbSet(Of TResult).Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) methods within my [DomainService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373%28VS.91%29.aspx). I also need to add the [IncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.includeattribute%28VS.91%29.aspx) to the navigation properties within metadata classes.

I make a *single* decision to have a related object transferred to the client and am forced to make *two* changes to implement it which seems a bit redundant.

I am considering making modifications to the T4 templates so that all navigation properties are automatically decorated with the IncludeAttribute.

I was a little worried about entities that were left over from previous requests being unintentionally sent to the client but my understanding is that the DomainService is stateless which should mean that this will not be the case, right?

> The point of the "DomainService" name is that it is the [stateless](http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-ViewModel-Pattern.aspx)
>   object that represents a specific domain that is characteristic of my
>   application.

[Another approach](http://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/visual-studio-add-in-for-domain-service-include-attribute/) that I have seen was to automatically apply Include attributes to any metadata files within the project. I would still need to create the metadata files though.

Are there any other dangers that I am not seeing? Is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: [This thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/95737/219510.aspx) helped me understanding the rationale behind it. hope it helps.

Comment: The OP there seems to have exactly the same question. I feel though, that the answers were missing the point a bit. In a stateless service and with no lazy loading, what value does the attribute add?

Comment: In the EF case, it doesn't add a lot. It's possible the double decision would allow you to constrain data from things like stored procedures that would otherwise return more information than you would want to expose from your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the EDMX T4 template to apply the IncludeAttribute automatically and it is working as expected.

One advantage of manually applying the attributes that I identified along the way was that you are able to control the volume of code that is generated on the client. Entities that are used only on the server can be excluded.

This was not an issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think you've identified the potential problem space. By making IncludeAttributes the default, your service will return whatever object graph you put together in memory.

The best way to implement this solution would be to create a custom DomainServiceDescriptionProvider ([here's a decent sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2659)) that infers the IncludeAttribute for the correct property types without you having to keep your metadata files up-to-date.

Comment: I was not able to find the sample that you mentioned above. Can you provide more details please?